# How to Reuse array in Vue app , declare it once & use in more than one file?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

i have an array of products

```
const products = [
 { id: 1, productname: "64GB Phone", qty: 1, price: 33070, image: 
 require('../assets/phone.png') },
```

i have added this into 3 files 
is their any way i can declare this in one file & call it in 3 files without writing the whole array ?

Comment: as the labels suggest, you can create `store.js` for global data states or using `Vuex`.

Answer (score 1):

One valid pattern is to use mixins:

```js
import { reusableMixin as products } from "@/mixins/reusableMixin"
const component = {
  mixins: [
    products
  ],
  data(){
    return {...}
  },
  ...
}
___________________________

export const reusableMixin = {
  data(){
    return {
      products: [...] 
    }
  }
  // or when piping 
  computed:{
    products_piped: {
      get(){
        return getFromAnywhereSync()
      },
      set(val){
        setSomeWhere(val)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make changes on this array and all pages get that change then import is not the correct way because if you change it in one component the other component will not take that change. if you want something like this you have to add it in store (vuex) tell us exacly what do you need it for to help you ^^

Comment: How to use vuex ? to store data in a vue app ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a prototype in your main.js file as follows:

```
Vue.prototype.$products = { 
  id: 1, productname: "64GB Phone", qty: 1, price: 33070, image: 
  require('../assets/phone.png') 
};
```

Then, use `this.$products` within your Vue components.

(You have an erroneous open square bracket here: `const products = [` in your example)